# Cognito Ignoring Default Email Verification Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I've created a user pool with the following relevant piece of a CloudFormation template:

```
VerificationMessageTemplate:
  DefaultEmailOption: CONFIRM_WITH_LINK
  EmailMessageByLink: Click {##here##} to verify this email address for your account.
  EmailSubjectByLink: Your Verification Link
```

When I log into the console, I see that "Verification type: Link" is correctly selected and the email subject and message are properly created.

However, when I use Amplify to call `Auth.verifyCurrentUserAttribute('email')`, Cognito sends the user a default email with a verification code instead of a link.

Am I missing something somewhere? Is there a reason why Cognito would be ignoring this setting?